# Navigation with obstacle avoidance without precise velocity measurement

Tags: control, path-planning

I'm working on autonomous navigation and obstacle avoidance using a few small, education-purpose differential drive robots. The robot's motor can be programmatically controlled via PWM but the robot itself does not come with any useful sensors (wheel encoders, IMU etc.) What I try to do now is to attach AR markers (like AruCo) to the robots to get their poses, but the velocity measurement comes from the finite differences of positions and headings, thus quite noise. This makes it challenging to use velocity-based local planning methods, like Dynamic Window. I've used a Extended Kalman Filter on the position measurement, but the outcome is still than ideal. The other constraint is that the update rate on the robot motor is bounded by the camera FPS (<60 fps), thus tracking the velocity precisely is not easy either. Are there other local planner I should try? Should I get additional sensors? Thanks very much!

Comment: Welcome to *Robotics* J Chris Li, but I'm afraid that *Unbounded Design Questions* are off-topic because there are many ways to solve any given design problem. We prefer *[practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask)*, so questions which ask for a list of approaches or a subjective recommendation on a method (for how to build something, how to accomplish something, what something is capable of, etc.) are off-topic. Please take a look at [ask] & [about] for more information on how stack exchange works.

Comment: @Ben Thanks Ben. Would a algorithm A vs B comparison work better? While there could still be subjective opinions, I can provide as much constraints as I can to base it on a concrete problem.

Comment: A vs B comparisons are not much better.  I think the problem is that there are many details in your question that are specific to your exact use-case which make this basically a design question and opinion based.  What might be too noisy and less than ideal for you might be just fine for some one else...  Will additional sensors help?  Maybe.  Will a different algorithm help?  Maybe.  This is a vague and open ended question.  We don't know enough about your situation to be able to help.

Comment: Hello, the question is currently too broad. It already contains more than 2 specific scopes (sensors, local planners), Maybe you can consider asking different details in different questions?